# Error while adding a `PdfPTable` to a document

Tags: c#, itext

I am facing with the

> Index was outside the bounds of the array

error while adding `PdfPTable` to document using `iTextShrap`. Below is the code

```
Document myDocument = new Document(PageSize.A3.Rotate());
PdfWriter.GetInstance(myDocument, new FileStream("payslip.pdf", FileMode.Create));
myDocument.Open();
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(35);
table.TotalWidth = myDocument.PageSize.Width - 80f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
List<PdfPCell> headRow = new List<PdfPCell>();
PdfPCell contractor = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
contractor.Colspan = 5;
headRow.Add(contractor);
PdfPCell workType = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Refractory Works"));
workType.Colspan = 5;
headRow.Add(workType);
PdfPCell supervisor = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
supervisor.Colspan = 4;
headRow.Add(supervisor);
PdfPCell paySlipHead = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
paySlipHead.Colspan = 10;
headRow.Add(paySlipHead);
PdfPCell paySlipMonth = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XXXXXXX"));
paySlipMonth.Colspan = 2;
headRow.Add(paySlipMonth);
PdfPCell blank = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
blank.Colspan = 9;
headRow.Add(blank);
PdfPRow rw = new PdfPRow(headRow.ToArray());

table.Rows.Add(rw);

myDocument.Add(table);
```

I am having no clue on what is going wrong. Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by you not respecting what is explained in the documentation, more specifically the part where I wrote:

> There’s a `PdfPRow` object in the `com.itextpdf.text.pdf` package, but you aren’t supposed
>   to address it directly. iText uses this class internally to store the cells that belong
>   to the same row. (iText in Action - Second Edition, section 4.1.1 "Your first Table", p94)

If you do not even take the time to take a look at the basic examples, you should not expect that you can write code that works.

Please take a look at the [SimpleTable3](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/tables/SimpleTable3) example. In this example, I don't use `PdfPRow`. Instead I add the `PdfPCell` objects straight to the `PdfPTable`:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(35);
table.setTotalWidth(document.getPageSize().getWidth() - 80);
table.setLockedWidth(true);
PdfPCell contractor = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
contractor.setColspan(5);
table.addCell(contractor);
PdfPCell workType = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Refractory Works"));
workType.setColspan(5);
table.addCell(workType);
PdfPCell supervisor = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
supervisor.setColspan(4);
table.addCell(supervisor);
PdfPCell paySlipHead = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"));
paySlipHead.setColspan(10);
table.addCell(paySlipHead);
PdfPCell paySlipMonth = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("XXXXXXX"));
paySlipMonth.setColspan(2);
table.addCell(paySlipMonth);
PdfPCell blank = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
blank.setColspan(9);
table.addCell(blank);
document.add(table);
```

You don't have to worry about rows: iText creates `PdfPRow` instances internally (**as documented**).

This is what the result looks like: [simple_table3.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/simple_table3.pdf)

[image]

No exception is thrown.